# Is it posssible to change shorcuts for chrome pdf viewer extensions by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to change shorcuts 'ctrl+w' to 'escape key' to close chrome-pdf viewer window.
I tried with content_scripts and injecting javascript functions but didn't work.
Is there any way to change or customizing shortcuts in chrome pdf viewer?

Comment: `I tried` perhaps your code is incorrect

Comment: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/  >>>> with this chrome extension i tried injecting script through content_script, manifest.json but didn't work..